# How do I adjust my tibble to get a grouped bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think the code itself I'm using for a grouped barchart is roughly correct. However, my tibble doesn't have a way to call the three categories I need (Views, Interactions, and Comments). I have a conceptual issue in making this work.

This is what I'm trying to execute in ggplot2:

```
bp_vic <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Day, y = value, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')
bp_vic
```

Value and fill may be off. However, I think the main issue is not having a proper category call.

My tibble has six columns. The last three are what I'm trying to plot. Integer counts for Views, Interactions, and Comments.

[This](https://github.com/davidmvermillion/LinkedInHardMode/blob/main/Analysis.R) is my script file and this is the [CSV](https://github.com/davidmvermillion/LinkedInHardMode/blob/main/LinkedInPostPerformancesDay25.csv) I'm generating my tibble from.

I have successfully executed this for individual columns only:

```
bp_v <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Day, y = Views)) + geom_col()
bp_v
```

```
dput(data)
structure(list(Day = c(-3L, -2L, -1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L), Category = c("SpaceForce", "CyberSecurity", 
"Celebration", "Update", "Update", "SpaceNews", "Data", "USSFExplained", 
"USSFExplained", "USSFExplained", "USSFExplained", "USSFExplained", 
"USSFExplained", "USSFExplained", "Nostalgia", "Data", "Publishing", 
"SpaceForce", "Military", "SpaceNews", "Publishing", "Office", 
"Office", "Office", "Office", "Data", "Update", "Space"), Type = c("Share", 
"Photo_1", "Photo_5", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Photo_1", "Text", 
"Photo_1", "Photo_1", "Photo_1", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Photo_1", 
"Photo_1", "Text", "Text", "Text", "Photo_3", "Text", "Text", 
"Photo_3", "Text", "Text", "Photo_3", "Photo_1", "Photo_1"), 
    Views = c(26L, 99L, 7106L, 517L, 655L, 828L, 2183L, 911L, 
    467L, 247L, 299L, 245L, 674L, 668L, 721L, 1358L, 383L, 701L, 
    281L, 1339L, 770L, 373L, 482L, 386L, 166L, 454L, 366L, 318L
    ), Interactions = c(0L, 0L, 125L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 16L, 17L, 
    10L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 18L, 13L, 
    6L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 11L, 6L, 10L), Comments = c(0L, 0L, 35L, 
    4L, 12L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 11L, 10L, 
    13L, 0L, 19L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput(data)` and paste the output in your question? So we can try and recreate your graph/issue?

Comment: Original post edited to add the output from ```dput(data)```.

Comment: Convert your tibble from wide to long using `pivot_wider`. Your tibble is not tidy because the column names provide data you need to construct your plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `tidyverse` to put the data into a useable (and tidy) format, before trying to plot the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  data %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = c(Views, Interactions, Comments),
    names_to = "Section",
    values_to = "values"
  )
```

New format

```
head(data)
# A tibble: 6 × 5
    Day Category      Type    Section      values
  <int> <chr>         <chr>   <chr>         <int>
1    -3 SpaceForce    Share   Views            26
2    -3 SpaceForce    Share   Interactions      0
3    -3 SpaceForce    Share   Comments          0
4    -2 CyberSecurity Photo_1 Views            99
5    -2 CyberSecurity Photo_1 Interactions      0
6    -2 CyberSecurity Photo_1 Comments          0
```

Then, you can plot the grouped bar chart.

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill = Section, y = values, x = Day)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

Output (though difficult to see most because of the 1 really high value)
[image]

Or you could easily plot the `Category` rather than the day if needed too, by having `x = Category` instead of `x = Day`.
[image]

If you would like to change the order of the categories, then you can make `Category` a factor, which you can do without changing the dataframe.

```
# Create order for the categories. If you want to do it by the number of views, then you can create the list from your dataframe.
level_order <- data %>%
  dplyr::filter(Section == "Views") %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(values)) %>%
  pull(Category) %>%
  unique()
  
# Then, set category as a factor and include the ordered categories.
ggplot(data, aes(fill = Section, y = values, x = factor(Category, level = level_order))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: How do you order the categories? I tried this but it didn't affect the chart when I plotted it. ```arrange(data, values, Category)```

Comment: @DavidMVermillion I have edited my answer to include how to change the order along the x-axis. Essentially, you need to make `Category` a factor to be able to change the order.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to filter by values of views within the categories instead of manually creating the order?

Comment: @DavidMVermillion I'm not quire sure what you're asking. Are you wanting to have the x-axis in order by `Category` with the highest number of views to the lowest number of views (left to right) (or vice-a-versa)? If not, can you provide a small example?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DavidMVermillion I've edited that ending part to show how to first get the list that you want, then you can plug for `level = ...`.